What's the most efficient algorithm to determine the line that has the maximum number of intersections with a set of polygons?
Given a set of polygons (2D), how can one find the line $L$ that intersects the polygons at the most number of points? For any convex polygon, this is always 2, and any line through the polygon works. A dart shape has 4 points, but the line needs to cross the concave part.
The best algorithm I have found runs in $O(N^3 \log N)$, where $N$ is the number of points or segments.
The motivation for the algorithm comes from considering that a line in the plane can be projected down to a point on a line where the most line segments overlap. If the direction of this best line $L$ is known ahead of time, it is quite easy to project all polygon segments to a line $P$ perpendicular to $L$ and use a simple sorting algorithm to count how many line segments are 'active' at each point, leading to $O(N \log N)$ work given a direction.
But how do we find the direction, given there are uncountably many directions to check? Imagine looking at this polygon set on-edge, and considering how it projects to $P$. As the target of the projection $P$ rotates, the projections of these points shift along $P$. However, the maximum intersections can only go up or down as two point projections cross each other on $P$. Each point does this with every other point, so there are now only $O(N^2)$ options. The product of the work and number of potential directions is $O(N^3 \log N)$.
My question is simply: is there a better approach in terms of big-O?
